# Unable to upload json file on hive using json serde

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hive-serde

I am trying to load json file using json serde. I have added the serde jar file successfully.

1) My json jar file placed on path /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/ 
I have run this command successfully

```
add jar hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar; converting to local hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar Added [/tmp/6f1a54b9-65c4-4e32-8e87-25d60ef775c6_resources/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar] to class path Added resources: [hdfs:///apps/hive/warehouse/lib/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar]
```

2) Now when i am trying to upload json file on this path /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/ or tmp/
 using ambari GUI. I am unable to upload it gives error 500. see attached image[image: error while uploading json file]
3) I have also tried this command but beacuse i am unable to upload json file. so, it doesnot work

> hadoop fs -put tmp/test.json /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/test.json

Kindly help me solving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the file into hive, first copy the file to an HDFS Location. Like below:

```
hadoop fs -put /complete_path_to_my_json/json_to_upload.json /app/hive/a_temp_location
```

Then once you have the table created with JSON SerDe like below:

```
create table if not exists my_json_table (id int, name string, designation string) row format serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.d.JsonSerDe';
```

You can load the data into the table with the following statement:

```
load data inpath '/app/hive/a_temp_location/json_to_upload.json' into table my_json_table;
```

Comment: My json file name test.json placed on desktop in my pc . now i am trying to upload it on hdfs directory using ambari gui it gives error 500 and not uploading on it. kindly see attached image i have edited question

Comment: Mostly it could be with the permission to upload to the directory. Please refer - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/115942/unable-to-load-json-file-via-ambari.html

Comment: unable to understand.. please help how to check if maria_dev has write permission on that directory or not?

Comment: Try to put a file to the location from console as maria_dev and see what happens!

Comment: From the console where you tried hadoop fs commands, execute the following: touch /tmp/testfile && hadoop fs -put /tmp/testfile /apps/hive

Comment: touch /tmp/test.json && hadoop fs -put /tmp/test.json /apps/hive/warehouse/lib/test.json .. this command executed without any error on shell –

Comment: Alright. Then try moving the file using the hadoop fs -put command to an HDFS location and then load it into the hive table from there.

Comment: Please try again to a different destination. The response doesn't seem valid.

Comment: You can provide the permission if you know the location where ambari tries to upload.